# Concat two pandas DataFrame with same column/index into one DataFrame

Tags: json, mongodb, pandas

I'm trying to concat multiples `pandas.DataFrame` to be saved in a MongoDB in just one collection, all the dataframes have the same index/columns and I wanted to save it, in just one document, using `to_json()` method. Having all the cells of the dataframe as dicts is probably a good approach.

To accomplish that I wanted to concat the dataframes like this:

```
df1:                
 index   A      B
 1     'A1'   'B1'
 2     'A2'   'B2'
 3     'A3'   'B3'

df2:
 index  A      B
 1    'a1'   'b1'
 2    'a2'   'b2'
 3    'a3'   'b3'
```

Expected solution:

```
df_sol:
 index    A                    B
 1        {d1:'A1', d2:'a1'}   {d1:'B1', d2:'b1'}
 2        {d1:'A2', d2:'a2'}   {d1:'B2', d2:'b2'}
 3        {d1:'A3', d2:'a3'}   {d1:'B3', d2:'b3'}
```

is there a way to accomplish that without using an iterator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.Panel` with `apply` + `pd.Series.to_dict`

```
pd.Panel(dict(d1=df1, d2=df2)).apply(pd.Series.to_dict, 0)

                              A                         B
index                                                    
1      {'d1': 'A1', 'd2': 'a1'}  {'d1': 'B1', 'd2': 'b1'}
2      {'d1': 'A2', 'd2': 'a2'}  {'d1': 'B2', 'd2': 'b2'}
3      {'d1': 'A3', 'd2': 'a3'}  {'d1': 'B3', 'd2': 'b3'}
```

---

This is assuming the columns you have labeled `index` are in fact the index.  Otherwise, make sure they are:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('index')
df2 = df2.set_index('index')
```

Comment: This solution its now giving a `DeprecationWarning : Panel is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.`
it's there a workaround to the `Panel` implementation ?

Comment: @PabloA open a new question.  Ask the identical question but reference that `pandas.Panel` is now deprecated and you need an alternative.

Comment: @PabloA I have an alternative waiting and others may even provide a better one.

Comment: Thanks @PabloA.  I've answered it (-:

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this bit of code:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('index')
df2 = df2.set_index('index')

df_int = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True, right_index=True,suffixes=('_d1','_d2'))

A_dict = df_int[['A_d1','A_d2']].rename(columns={'A_d1':'d1','A_d2':'d2'}).to_dict(orient='records')
B_dict = df_int[['B_d1','B_d2']].rename(columns={'B_d1':'d1','B_d2':'d2'}).to_dict(orient='records')

df_sol = pd.DataFrame({'A':A_dict,'B':B_dict})

df_sol
```

Output:

```
                          A                         B
0  {'d1': 'A1', 'd2': 'a1'}  {'d1': 'B1', 'd2': 'b1'}
1  {'d1': 'A2', 'd2': 'a2'}  {'d1': 'B2', 'd2': 'b2'}
2  {'d1': 'A3', 'd2': 'a3'}  {'d1': 'B3', 'd2': 'b3'}
```