# combine two pandas dataframe into one dataframe "dict type cell" (pd.Panel deprecated)

Tags: json, mongodb, pandas, dataframe, panel

I'm trying to concat multiples pandas.DataFrame to be saved in a mongodb in just one collection, all the dataframes have the same index/columns and I wanted to save it, in just one document, using to_json() method. Having all the cells of the dataframe as dicts, its probably a good approach. To accomplish that I wanted to concat the dataframes like this:

```
df1:                
 index   A      B
 1     'A1'   'B1'
 2     'A2'   'B2'
 3     'A3'   'B3'

df2:
 index  A      B
 1    'a1'   'b1'
 2    'a2'   'b2'
 3    'a3'   'b3'
```

Expected solution:

```
df_sol:
 index    A                    B
 1        {d1:'A1', d2:'a1'}   {d1:'B1', d2:'b1'}
 2        {d1:'A2', d2:'a2'}   {d1:'B2', d2:'b2'}
 3        {d1:'A3', d2:'a3'}   {d1:'B3', d2:'b3'}
```

the aproach that im using is

```
pd.Panel(dict(d1=df1, d2=df2)).apply(pd.Series.to_dict, 0)

                              A                         B
index                                                    
1      {'d1': 'A1', 'd2': 'a1'}  {'d1': 'B1', 'd2': 'b1'}
2      {'d1': 'A2', 'd2': 'a2'}  {'d1': 'B2', 'd2': 'b2'}
3      {'d1': 'A3', 'd2': 'a3'}  {'d1': 'B3', 'd2': 'b3'}
```

but `pd.Panel` its deprecated `DeprecationWarning : Panel is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.`its there a workaround using just `pandas`?
thanks!

[Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43264668/5318634)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**
`pd.concat` + other stuff

```
pd.Series(
    pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['d1', 'd2']).stack().to_dict('index')
).unstack()

                              A                             B
1  {'d1': ''A1'', 'd2': ''a1''}  {'d1': ''B1'', 'd2': ''b1''}
2  {'d1': ''A2'', 'd2': ''a2''}  {'d1': ''B2'', 'd2': ''b2''}
3  {'d1': ''A3'', 'd2': ''a3''}  {'d1': ''B3'', 'd2': ''b3''}
```

---

**Explanation**
I want to get `[1, 2, 3]` and `['A', 'B']` into the index and `['d1', 'd2']` as the columns.

I start with `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['d1', 'd2'])

         d1          d2      
          A     B     A     B
index                        
1      'A1'  'B1'  'a1'  'b1'
2      'A2'  'B2'  'a2'  'b2'
3      'A3'  'B3'  'a3'  'b3'
```

Which almost gets me there.  If I follow that with a `stack`, it will drop the last level of the columns into the last level of the index:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['d1', 'd2']).stack()

           d1    d2
index              
1     A  'A1'  'a1'
      B  'B1'  'b1'
2     A  'A2'  'a2'
      B  'B2'  'b2'
3     A  'A3'  'a3'
      B  'B3'  'b3'
```

And this is what I want.  From here I can use `.to_dict('index')`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['d1', 'd2']).stack().to_dict('index')

{(1, 'A'): {'d1': "'A1'", 'd2': "'a1'"},
 (1, 'B'): {'d1': "'B1'", 'd2': "'b1'"},
 (2, 'A'): {'d1': "'A2'", 'd2': "'a2'"},
 (2, 'B'): {'d1': "'B2'", 'd2': "'b2'"},
 (3, 'A'): {'d1': "'A3'", 'd2': "'a3'"},
 (3, 'B'): {'d1': "'B3'", 'd2': "'b3'"}}
```

And pass that back to the `pd.Series` constructor to get a series of dictionaries.

```
pd.Series(
    pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['d1', 'd2']).stack().to_dict('index')
)

1  A    {'d1': ''A1'', 'd2': ''a1''}
   B    {'d1': ''B1'', 'd2': ''b1''}
2  A    {'d1': ''A2'', 'd2': ''a2''}
   B    {'d1': ''B2'', 'd2': ''b2''}
3  A    {'d1': ''A3'', 'd2': ''a3''}
   B    {'d1': ''B3'', 'd2': ''b3''}
dtype: object
```

The only thing left to do is `unstack` which I show in the solution above.

Comment: in the first option, the second operation (the `groupby` ) lost the right index, its there a way to fix it ?

Comment: I've edited since then.  I believe what I have now is superior.

Answer (score 2):

This is a completely different concept that I am having fun with.

---

You can create a subclass of `dict` where we define addition to be a dictionary merge.

```
from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge

class mdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return(mdict(merge(self, other)))


df1.applymap(lambda x: mdict(d1=x)) + df2.applymap(lambda x: mdict(d2=x))

                                  A                             B
index                                                            
1      {'d1': ''A1'', 'd2': ''a1''}  {'d1': ''B1'', 'd2': ''b1''}
2      {'d1': ''A2'', 'd2': ''a2''}  {'d1': ''B2'', 'd2': ''b2''}
3      {'d1': ''A3'', 'd2': ''a3''}  {'d1': ''B3'', 'd2': ''b3''}
```